# How to use VueJS axios-oauth-client and google photos api?

Tags: vuejs2, axios, vue-cli-3

I'm using vue cli and I try to get album list from my google photos account.

I'm using axios-oauth-client and I try to implement this code:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const oauth = require('axios-oauth-client');
const getAuthorizationCode = oauth.client(axios.create(), {
  url: 'https://oauth.com/2.0/token',
  grant_type: 'authorization_code',
  client_id: 'foo',
  client_secret: 'bar',
  redirect_uri: '...',
  code: '...',
  scope: 'baz',
});

const auth = await getAuthorizationCode(); // => { "access_token": "...", "expires_in": 900, ... }
```

As described in [here](https://github.com/compwright/axios-oauth-client#readme) and I can't understand how do I get the authorization code aka code in this implementation.

I managed to do this call in postman but I'm unable to do it using axios.

**Postman**
[image]

**My Code**

```
async function getToken() {
  const getAuthorizationCode = oauth.client(axios.create(), {
    url: "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    client_id:
      "**********.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    client_secret: "***********",
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:8080/oauth2/callback",
    code: "...",
    scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly"
  });

  const auth = await getAuthorizationCode(); // => { "access_token": "...", "expires_in": 900, ... }

  console.log(auth);
}

getToken();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I still didn't manage to make it works but I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52832574/5183681) answer which I will try to check.

**UPDATE#2**

Eventually I ended up using google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app) for Oauth2 using php and I took their git example as a base project.
In order to do it I also needed to use database to save the tokens and especially the refresh token which I use to refresh the access token every time I receive 401.

Comment: So what's the problem you're running into? Which part of your code doesn't give the expected results?

Comment: Hey @TommyF, I can't figure out how to redirect to the google login to get the auth code. It's a website that doesn't have a login since it's a portfolio and I try to show photos stored in a google photos account.

Comment: So your code is not being executed or is not returning a token or what exactly is the issue you run into? Any error messages? Can you see network traffic regarding this request? You need to provide a bit more specific info for others to provide any help :)

Comment: Also maybe check out Auth0, they offer a great way to integrate oauth, have good docs and examples for getting up and running with Vue (or any other framework for that matter) if that's an option for you.

Comment: Thanks @TommyF, I don't think the error is relevant since it's malform token error cause I don't have a token to send. I will check Auth0. I try to find different methods since I build a portfolio page without backend and without login and I just want to generate my gallery using photos hosted by Google Photos so I don't understand how should I implement the required login for Google Photo API.

Thanks!